# Kendo report error in publish environment. Till yesterday it was working fine. No any problem running locally

Tags: caching, kendo-ui, iis-7, telerik-reporting

While opening kendo report in published environment, It gives error:

> "Error registering viewer with the service. An Error has occured.
>   Incorrect value (null) deserialized. Make sure you are using
>   CacheStorage inside single-instance application deployment only."

The local environment is fine.
Snapshot of the error:

[image: errror]

some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to ask for help in the official documents, it seems that there is something wrong with Telerik Reporting Rest service.
https://www.telerik.com/search?q=error+registering+the+viewer+with+the+service.
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/telerik-reporting-rest-conception?_ga=2.75324762.973983418.1591344123-1158309109.1591344123

Answer (score 0):

I am using .net core 5.0 and In my case, I just add the below code in **cspoj** file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I hope it will help for needy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting this folder ~Users/AppPoolName/AppData/Local/Temp/AppPoolName

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me when I ran CCleaner and removed Windows temporary files, etc.  I fixed it by going to `C:\Windows\Temp` and deleting the folder that has the same name as my Telerik Report Visual Studio Project.